# Nagata's Criterion on Factoriality Proof Explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, localization, unique-factorization-domains

I was reading about [Nagata's Criterion](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AFU). I have two questions,

(i) How is the *multiplicatively closed subset generated by prime elements* defined?

**My thoughts:** Let $S$ be the set of generating prime elements. I assume the definition is: the intersection of all multiplicatively closed subgroup containing $S$ - this is defined, as the set of non units is multiplicatively closed.

(ii) In the 2nd paragraph, how did we obtain (the equality, and the statement)

> $S^{-1}A/xS^{-1}A = S^{-1}(A/(x))$ is a domain or zero.

why does this imply

> $x$ maps to a unit or prime.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a standard notation, but let's denote the set of prime elements of an integral domain by $P_A$, so you can define the set $$S=\Bigl\{\prod_{i\in \Bbb N}x_i:x_i\in A^{\times}\cup X,\; X\subset P_A\Bigr\}.$$

Then $S$ is a set whose elements are (finite) products of units and  primes and we say that $S$ is a *multiplicatively closed subset generated by primes*.

For a concrete example, let's take $A=\Bbb{Z}$ and $X=\{2,3\}$, in this case we have $$S=\{\pm 2^a\cdot 3^b\},$$ because $\Bbb{Z}^{\times}=\{\pm 1\}$. Analogously, we can take $X$ to be the set of prime numbers of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$, etc.

> $S^{-1}A/xS^{-1}A = S^{-1}(A/(x))$ is a domain or zero.

This really should be an isomorphism and moreover in the RHS it should be $\bar{S}$, where $\bar{S}=\{\bar{s}: s\in S\}$ such that the classes are taken mod $(x)$.

To get the isomorphism we can define $S^{-1}A/xS^{-1}A\rightarrow \bar{S}^{-1}(A/(x))$ given by $r/s+xS^{-1}A\mapsto \bar{r}/\bar{s}$ for all $r\in A$ and $s\in S$. I leave it to you to prove that the above map is indeed an isomorphism.

Now, as $x$ is prime, then $A/(x)$ is an integral domain, hence $\bar{S}^{-1}(A/(x))$ is either an integral domain or the zero ring, so by the isomorphism we get that $S^{-1}A/xS^{-1}A$ is either an integral domain or the zero ring.

If $S^{-1}A/xS^{-1}A$ in an integral domain, then $xS^{-1}A$ is a prime ideal, but this is also a principal ideal, so its generator $x$ must be a prime element.

Otherwise, if $S^{-1}A/xS^{-1}A$ is the zero ring, then $xS^{-1}A$ is the whole ring, so $x$ must be an unit.

---

I personally don't like how Nagata's criterion is presented in the Stack Project, because I think the results (1) and (2) should be presented as independent lemmas prior to the main result:  $A$ is a UFD if and only if every element of $A$ has a factorization into irreducibles and $S^{-1}A$ is a UFD.

I prefer the exposition that is given in P. L. Clark' [notes on factorization in integral domains](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/factorization2010.pdf). Nagata's criterion is theorem 62 in the above notes, or alternatively, you can check the [notes on commutative algebra](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf) by the same author where this result is theorem 15.39.

Finally, it's good to have a look at the original statement that was given by Nagata, so I recommend you to check his [paper](https://www.projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1261154156) where his criterion is stated in lemma 2.

Comment: In fact, the way they stated the criterion is useless: how one can verify that $A$ is atomic in practice? Instead, if one replaces this by ACCP then the things change cause many examples are Noetherian.

Comment: @user26857 well, I guess they wanted to state the criterion in the most general way, theoretically speaking.